# Problems with navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been having problems with the bootstrap navbar i want to specifically align the dropdown to the right. I did it but whenever I click it the menu goes all the way to left. If you dont understand what i mean go to this website https://escapeavis.herokuapp.com/login
Login With These Cred Btw i made this website.
Username: Admin

Password: Java6080

Now see where it says Admin on the navbar and click it and go to member now you will see what i wanted the Admin part at the right of the screen but when you click it the menu goes somewhere else. Can Anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

Add this to your CSS file on the member's page.